Can you pass a variable into a classes __str__ to change the output?
I want to pass a variable into str (inside of a class) to change its output. For example:
class Basic:
    def __str__(self, specialCase=False):
        if specialCase == True:
            return "x"
        return "y"

example = Basic()
print(example)                    #this prints y
print(example,specialCase=True)   #this hopefully prints x?

Is there any way to do this?
I have tried to send the variable with print(example(specialCase=True)) and print(example,specialCase=True) but they both just respond with errors.

This does not work and you should not do this. functions in python have fixed parameters, you can't/shouldn't try to change this. print is much more than a renamed version of obj.__str__. Instead, print only calls it.

Just make a method that returns your special case, and use print(example.special_case()).

Would a better approach be setting some class (maybe instance) variable and checking if its true inside of str?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Not with __str__, but you can use format specifiers with __format__
class Basic
    def __format__(self, format_spec):
        if format_spec == 'spec':
            return 'x'
        return 'y'

example = Basic()

print(f'{example:spec}, {example}') # x, y

